# How to pass a variable from settings.py to a view?

Tags: django, variables

I'm getting the project path in my Django app in settings.py using:

```
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

I would like to use the PROJECT_PATH value in other views, such as for locating the path to files in my static path. How can I make this into an accessible variable?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Use `from django.conf import settings` but mind that `settings` is not a module. The [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#using-settings-in-python-code) clearly explains that and your use case.

Answer (score 32):

```
from django.conf import settings as conf_settings
project_path = conf_settings.PROJECT_PATH
```

Answer (score 7):

1. in `settings.py` add

   ```
   DOMAIN = "example.com"
   ```
2. `views.py`

   ```
   from django.conf import settings

   DOMAIN = settings.DOMAIN
   ```
3. lets try to `output it`:

   ```
   print(DOMAIN)

   print(type(DOMAIN))
   ```
4. `output will be`:

   ```
   example.com

   <class 'str'>
   ```