# Pass a variable from custom settings into a Django view

Tags: python, django

I know how to access the settings module (as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984648/how-to-pass-a-variable-from-settings-py-to-a-view)) but I have a number of custom settings modules that extend `settings.py` and I'm not sure how to access it in my view.  It's available in my template but I can't find any information on how to access it in the settings.  `os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"]` correctly returns the string of my intended settings module, but since it's just a string it doesn't have my variables on it.

custom_settings1.py

```
from settings import *  # noqa: F403

SITE_ID = 1
SITE_NAME = "MY SITE"
```

Comment: The duplicate you've included shows exactly how to access settings in a view.. what isn't working?

Comment: @sayse I can get things from `settings.py` no problem, but not from the module that extends it.

Comment: You should show this module that "extends" settings. It's hard to tell what you mean.

Comment: Are you trying to access the settings in your templates?

Comment: @Brobin In my view.  It's already correctly working in my template.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Added.  I thought this was a common use case?

Comment: I would import custom_settings in your settings file.

Comment: @Brobin Custom_settings changes based on which site I'm running so not sure how to do that

Comment: But since it's available in my template there must be a way to get it in the view

Answer (score 0):

To use settings in a view, you just import it as in the cited post.

```
def settings_view(request):
    from django.conf import settings
    context = { 
        'settings': settings
    }
    return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

And in your template:

```
My setting is {% settings.my_setting %}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my project, I use a custom context processor to inject settings variables into my templates. This way you don't have to add it to the context of every view function/class.

```
# app/context.py
from django.conf import settings


def my_settings(request):
    return { 'MY_CUSTOM_SETTING': settings.MY_CUSTOM_SETTING }
```

Then you add it to your context processors in the the `TEMPLATE` setting.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                ...
                'app.context.my_settings',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Now it is available in any template!

```
{{ MY_CUSTOM_SETTING }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Far from being a "common use case", you have this exactly the wrong way round.

Almost always, you will define custom settings directly in settings.py; that way they are added to the object you get when you do `from django.conf import settings`.

Very occasionally you might want to define settings in separate modules; in which case, you import them *from there into the main settings.py*, not the other way round as you have them.

settings.py is the canonical place for settings to go.

Comment: Different parts of our site use different settings files, though, so I'm not really sure how that would work.

Comment: But that doesn't make sense. Settings are project-wide. I suspect you are using settings for something that are not intended for.

Comment: Every job I've ever had used them this way, and I've worked for large, well-known industries.  Oh well; I'll figure something else out.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/settings/#custom-default-settings

Comment: I can't see the relevance of that link at all, I'm afraid.